# regex filter in replace module for ansible

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, ansible, pcre

Trying to get a regex replace in an ansible role for update autoscales going.
In my CFT I have the following mapping:

```
  DevRegionSettings:
    us-east-1:
    primaryZone: us-east-1a
    # secondaryZone: us-east-1b

    # autoscale is wrong at point of instantiation
    amiAutoscale: ami-234sefsrwerwer21
    amiDB:        ami-12313123
    amiCoord:     ami-12312312
    amiWeb:       ami-13123123
    amiWorker:    ami-12312312
```

I want to replace just the value of `amiAutoscale` with the latest ami that I find earlier on in the role.

I'm a regex noob and cannot figure it out for the life of me.
Been playing around with some of the regex from this thread:
[Regex to match key in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461404/regex-to-match-key-in-yaml)

But still cant get it to do what I want :(

Any help would be appreciated!

The ansible task I had running was as follows:

```
- name: Replacing ami in the Dev Cloudformation Template
  replace:
    regexp: '(^\s*(?P<key>\w+_amiAutoscale):\s*(?P<value>\d+))'
    replace: "{{ latest_ami.image_id }}"
    path: "$path_to_cft.yaml"
```

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of issues with your regex:

- `\w+_amiAutoscale` - The line `amiAutoscale: ami-234sefsrwerwer21` does not have an `_` before amiAutoscale
- `(?P<value>\d+)` - `ami-234sefsrwerwer21` is not a sequence of digits.

This worked for me, but may be too open of a pattern: `(^\s*(?P<key>amiAutoscale):\s*(?P<value>.+))`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/76VGlJ/1

Comment: Ahhh ok. I see where I was going wrong. Put your regex in a generator to explain it to me. I hate reading regex just raw. I tested your expression against my entire template and it only found the one match that I wanted so I think this does the trick! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Replacing ami in the Dev Cloudformation Template
  replace:
   regexp: '(^\s*(?P<key>amiAutoscale):\s*(?P<value>.+))'
   replace: "{{ latest_ami.image_id }}"
   path: "$path_to_cft.yaml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not match because the regex expect to match 1+ word characters followed by an underscore `\w+_` right after the starting whitespace characters `^\s*` which are not in the data.

Also, in the named capturing group `(?P<value>\d+)` you match 1+ digits which does not match `ami-234sefsrwerwer21`

What you also might do for your example data is to use only 2 capturing groups and a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in the second group to specify what you would allow to match:

`^\s*(?P<key>amiAutoscale)\s*:\s*(?P<value>[\w-]+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9riaS/1)